# Advanced Custom Fields category link

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm struggling with this even after looking at the documentation but all I'm wanting to do is link to a category. I have created a taxonomy field to select categories. Everything is working apart from when I add

```
<a href="<?php echo the_sub_field('category_link','option' ); ?>"></a>
```

I just get the ID of the category but I want the name. This is all within a repeater as I'm creating a menu but I need help getting the name and not the ID.

any help please?

Comment: can you try with this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an option of selecting only one taxonomy.

Then write the query:

```
    <?php $term_id = get_sub_field('category_link');
    if( $term_id):
        $term_name = get_cat_name( $term_id ) ;
        $term_url = get_category_link( $term_id ); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo term_url; ?>"><?php echo $term_name; ?></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

OR

If there are multiple category terms, then place this query:

```
     <?php 
    $terms = get_sub_field('category_link');
    if( $terms ):
        foreach( $terms as $term_id ): 
            $term_name = get_cat_name( $term_id ) ;
            $term_url = get_category_link( $term_id ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo term_url; ?>"><?php echo $term_name; ?></a>
   <?php endforeach;  endif;    ?>
```

Now place your category term url & name in the anchor tag.

Comment: I've added your code above and added <?php esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ;?> but that doesn't work...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I saw just now, you said you have selected Category from the Taxonomy field in the backend, right?

Comment: Is it a category or a custom taxonomy in the taxonomy field?

Comment: It's just category...no custom taxonomy

Comment: I am really sorry for so much inconvenience, please revert back the Term Object to Term id in the custom field in the backend & find my updated code.

Comment: Thankyou, i have updated but how do create a link to the category? what do I need to add in my <a href=""></a>

Comment: Thankyou for your help but I can still not get this to work. see screenshot for what i have https://ibb.co/d01oFa

Comment: where is this line: $term_id = get_sub_field('category_link');

Comment: Include above "$term_id" line & remove "?>" just after the "if($term_id):" condition tag.

Comment: Thankyou, this now works. Thankyou very much for your help.

Comment: Any time brother.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It can give all your terms under the preferred taxonomy. Just give your taxonomy name in the below code

```
<?php $terms= get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy name',
) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Ok I'm getting a list of my categories which is further than I've got so far but how do I make links for the categories?

Comment: get_term_link( $term ); inside the foreach can give you the link.

<a href="<?php esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ;?>"> <?php echo $term->name; ?> </a>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me know have you selected Term_id in the custom field which you have created & also let me know you can select one or more taxonomy through that custom field.

Comment: I have selected term ID

Comment: Please select term object & perform the query mentioned in the other answer.